# Can one indicate more than one purpose of trip when completing Form I-131, Application for Travel Document when applying for a reentry permit?

Tags: usa, resident-permit

Can one indicate more than one purpose of trip when completing [Form I-131, Application for Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/i-131) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200823021419/https://www.uscis.gov/i-131)) when applying for a reentry permit? (e.g., work + medical reason + vacation)

I don't see anything mentioned in the  [Instructions for Application for Travel Document](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-131instr.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200823021430/https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-131instr.pdf)).

[image]

I'm prudent as I read on
https://lawandborder.com/guide-to-reentry-permits/#comment-156602 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200822193604/https://lawandborder.com/guide-to-reentry-permits/)):

> A common goal of the questioning is to determine whether you were actually abroad for the purpose stated in the RP. If not, the presumption you’ve maintained LPR status is lost.

Comment: Wouldn't specifying more than one reason just make it *harder* for you to prove that you had been abroad for all those reasons? Or are you expecting to just need to prove that you were abroad for *one* of the reasons you gave?

Comment: @GregHewgill harder but still easy. I have no expectation: I don't know how this work.